# Stratified Sampling in R- sample size issues

Tags: r, resampling, splitstackshape

I am trying to do stratified sampling in R using the stratified function in the splitstackshape package. I have four strata (labeled 1:4). When setting the size = 1, it returns one row belonging to each strata (great!). However, I'm not able to increase my sample size by one.

I want it to select 5 rows: 4 of them belonging to strata 1:4, and the fifth one belonging to strata #1 (the strata that covers the most amount of area in my study site); and ideally this will be done without replacement so the second row that is sampled from strata #1 will not be the same as the first.

Setting the size = 1 - 1.99 always returns 1 row from each strata (4 total). Setting the size = 2 returns 8 rows (2 from each strata).

**Dataframe**

```
homer_join_strat<- structure(list(cluster = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 
4L), waterbody = c("Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", 
"Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer", "Homer"
), transect_number = 1:26, BLG = c(75, 38.4204909284952, 77.634011090573, 
82.1917808219178, 119.341563786008, 22.5422667501565, 155.275381552754, 
81.1332904056665, 37.037037037037, 73.2824427480916, 71.608040201005, 
208.806818181818, 116.504854368932, 119.775421085465, 104.408352668213, 
117.391304347826, 12.0603015075377, 93.5593220338983, 166.795366795367, 
20, 91.566265060241, 70.8860759493671, 0, 44.8765893792072, 0, 
3.96563119629874), GSF = c(0, 6.4034151547492, 11.090573012939, 
16.4383561643836, 4.11522633744856, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.58015267175573, 
0, 21.3068181818182, 0, 0, 6.96055684454756, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), LMB = c(51.3157894736842, 83.2443970117396, 73.9371534195933, 
71.2328767123288, 28.8065843621399, 37.5704445835942, 59.721300597213, 
38.6349001931745, 66.6666666666667, 77.8625954198473, 67.8391959798995, 
63.9204545454545, 46.6019417475728, 22.4578914535246, 6.96055684454756, 
13.0434782608696, 24.1206030150754, 40.6779661016949, 60.2316602316602, 
56, 28.9156626506024, 55.6962025316456, 20.2360876897133, 31.413612565445, 
0, 31.7250495703899), YLB = c(0, 0, 14.7874306839187, 0, 4.11522633744856, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.63320463320463, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BLC = c(7.89473684210526, 12.8068303094984, 7.39371534195933, 
10.958904109589, 0, 0, 3.9814200398142, 0, 3.7037037037037, 13.7404580152672, 
11.3065326633166, 12.7840909090909, 3.88349514563107, 3.74298190892077, 
0, 0, 0, 4.06779661016949, 0, 16, 9.63855421686747, 5.06329113924051, 
20.2360876897133, 22.4382946896036, 0, 7.93126239259749), WHC = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.9814200398142, 0, 7.40740740740741, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 7.48596381784155, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.126582278481, 0, 
4.48765893792072, 0, 0), RSF = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.9442601194426, 
0, 0, 13.7404580152672, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 27.7992277992278, 
0, 4.81927710843374, 0, 0, 4.48765893792072, 0, 0), CCF = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.7037037037037, 0, 0, 0, 3.88349514563107, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 8.13559322033898, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), BLB = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.52272727272727, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-26L))
```

**Code**

```
stratified(homer_join_strat, "cluster",  size=.06)
stratified(homer_join_strat, "cluster",  size=.07)
stratified(homer_join_strat, "cluster",  size=.09)
stratified(homer_join_strat, "cluster",  size=2)
```

Does anyone have experience using this function to select a number of rows that does not equal or is not a multiple of the number of strata in the data?

*I am able to have it select 1, 2, 3, rows (in order of square area) by setting the size = .06, .07, .09 respectively (why I thought a number between 1-1.99 would give me 5 rows selected*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry about that, dataframe/code added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the documentation on the function you are using "If size is a named vector, the function will check to see whether the length of the vector matches the number of groups and that the names match the group names" - it then goes on to provide an example of exactly what your question asks.

```
  DF <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:100,
  A = sample(c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD", "EE"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  B = rnorm(100), C = abs(round(rnorm(100), digits=1)),
  D = sample(c("CA", "NY", "TX"), 100, replace = TRUE),
  E = sample(c("M", "F"), 100, replace = TRUE))

  stratified(DF, "D", c(CA = 5, NY = 3, TX = 2))
```

Comment: I did see/try that but was still getting errors. Switching my cluster categories to letters instead of numbers ended up working. Thanks for your help!